# SQL: how to self union arbitrary times

Tags: sql, sql-server

Assume I have a table like

```
Name  Value
Cat   10
Dog   15
```

Now given an input parameter "N", self union the table "N" times by creating a new column that has value 0 to N - 1 for each origin row. For example if N is 2, the resultant table should be

```
Name  Value  Count
Cat   10     0
Cat   10     1
Dog   15     0
Dog   15     1
```

If "N" is 4, the resultant table should be

```
Name  Value  Count
Cat   10     0
Cat   10     1
Cat   10     2
Cat   10     3
Dog   15     0
Dog   15     1
Dog   15     2
Dog   15     3
```

How to write a SQL statement for SQL Server that takes an input parameter "N" to produce the table as shown above?

Thanks

Comment: please tag the dbms being used

Comment: you could start by saying what RDBMS and version you are using. MySQL?, SQL Server?, Oracle?, POstgresql?....

Answer (score 5):

Union is the wrong word here, CROSS JOIN is what is needed.

On most platforms you could do it like this with a recursive CTE and cross join.

```
WITH numberList as
(
   SELECT <input number here> AS NUM
   UNION ALL
   SELECT NUM-1 
   FROM numberList
   WHERE NUM-1 >= 0
)
SELECT t.name, t.value, numberList.num
FROM tablename, numberList
```

If you expect num to be large (eg over 10k) you should not do it this way.  Instead (on most platforms) you should make a temporary table with an generated index/sequence.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is generating the numbers using a recursive cte and performing a cross-join.

```
declare @n int = 5;
with nums(n) as (select 0 
                 union all 
                 select n+1 from nums where n < @n-1)
select t.*,num.n
from tablname t 
cross join nums num
```